# How to capture 11 digit preceded by two or three or four characters , a char could be a dot using Regex

Tags: java, regex

I need to search in a HTML page a sequence of digits that could be like that:

`p.fg 67389109321`  or  `pfg 67389109321` or  `p.f 67389109321`

After parsing the HTML page I transform it in a string:

```
 String  Pagestring  = Page.toString().toLowerCase().replaceAll("  <[^>]+>","");
```

and using this Regex to capture the 11 digits:

```
final Matcher m = Pattern.compile(("(?<!\\d)\\d{11}(?!\\d)")).matcher(Page );
```

But it captures the first instance of 11 digits. I need to include the above options.

Comment: You already checked if leading and or trailing chars are digits, almost got it then. Just proceed same way using the possible leading sequences. Some quick help, non capturing sequences are enclosed between `(?:` and `)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straight forward: define the possible beginnings and separate them by "or" (`|`), then go for the 11 digits:

```
(p\.fg|pfg|p\.f) \d{11}
```

This means:

- `(`: delimiter for the or operation
- `p\.fg`: literal `pf.g`
- `|`: or
- `pfg`: literal `pfg`
- `|`: or
- `p\.f`: literal `p.f`
- `)`: delimiter for the or operation
- : literal space
- `\d{11}`: eleven digits

[Try it online](https://regex101.com/r/hdNVBx/1)

That said, removing HTML tags the way you do (`replaceAll("  <[^>]+>","");`) is not reliable. Use a HTML specific tool like [HtmlAgilityPack](http://html-agility-pack.net/). That regex might fail on HTML like

```
<tag attribute=">"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Regex**: [`p(?:\.?fg|\.f)\s\d{11}`](https://regex101.com/r/HBvDV2/1)

Details:

- `(?:)` Non-capturing group
- `|` Or
- `\s` Matches any whitespace character

**Java code**:

```
String string = "p.fg 67389109321 or  pfg 67389109321 or  p.f 67389109321";
Matcher matches = Pattern.compile("p(?:\\.?fg|\\.f)\\s\\d{11}").matcher(string);
while (matches.find()) {
    System.out.println(matches.group(0));
}
```

Output:

```
p.fg 67389109321
pfg 67389109321
p.f 67389109321
```

[Code demo](http://rextester.com/DEOPQ81960)